# Multi region availability of user pools in aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, scalability, low-latency, aws-userpools

I am working on SAAS Application, where the world wide users will authenticate to our system. We decided to use AWS Cognito as an identity platform. For greater availability and low latency for the authentication, we decided to replicate userpools in multiple needed regions and sync among them. Can anyone please suggest me to do a better architecture for this problem? Or any scalable alternate solution?

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck on this problem too. Have you found a better solution?